# how to load background image without border

Tags: html, css, image

i have to load an image inside an anchor tag .

```
<a> <img calss="imageclass"/></a>
```

if load like this iam getting border around the image. 
I have tried everything like border: 0 and border-style:none but nothing works.

i have one solution, if i use div element instead of img it comes without any border.

please help me how to load this image without border and not using div element.

Comment: Show HTML/CSS. Also, check if your image has border (not html element)

Comment: image not having border , is there any way to remove border ? thanks Justinas

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your css:

```
a, img {
  border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  ArinCool. I have tried this but still border there .

Comment: can you post your code with the actual image? Or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwj2zwg6/1/). Here it is

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" style="border: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Thnaks junaid .. i am sorry this one works with src as i told i have to load it from css only.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your image via css code ... like this

`#bgimg { background: url("http://www.staticimages.co/seemeagain/upgrade-sprite.png") -35px -3px;
 display:block;width: 25px;height: 25px;float: left;
}
and stop using img tag for uploading background image , use span tag and call your bgimg tag inside there .`